# finding and replacing text

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, sudo

Does any one know how to find and replace text in a file. it can be implimented into a bash file. i would like to find the line and the output the text to it the file can only be opened with the root sudo account.

Comment: this is not a duplicate i would like to have a answer that explains it in more detial and what i have to put were i.e. the location of the text file the text to find and the text to replace

Comment: @Jhondoe That's what manuals are for: `man sed`.

Comment: i did not know what sed was untill the first answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic example of `sed` usage using this as `test.txt`:

```
one two
three two four
two five
```

To replace `two` with `foo` in that file:

```
sed -i 's/foo/two/g' test.txt
```

What that means:

- `sed` is the name of the command, you'll find lots of tutorials ([e.g.](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/worlds-best-introduction-to-sed/)) and other documentation online, in addition to `man sed`.
- `-i` means edit a file in place.
- `'s/foo/two/g'`: the `s` indicates substitute first term for the second, the `g` (global) indicates for all instances in each line (not just the first).  Always remember to 'enclose' this.